# Android Layout - Button Width

Tags: android, android-layout

I've currently created a simple custom dialog fragment as shown below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#202020"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/custom_confirmation_dialog_title"
        android:background="@drawable/title_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#EEEEEE" />

    <TextView
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/custom_confirmation_dialog_message"
        android:text="Message goes here!"
        android:textColor="#EEEEEE" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/custom_confirmation_dialog_positive_button"
            android:text="Text for button 1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0px" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/custom_confirmation_dialog_negative_button"
            android:text="Longer text for button 2"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0px" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In conjunction with the following Java code:

```
class CustomConfirmationDialog extends DialogFragment

{
 public CustomConfirmationDialog() {}


 public static CustomConfirmationDialog newInstance()
 {
  CustomConfirmationDialog customConfirmationDialog =
    new CustomConfirmationDialog();
  customConfirmationDialog.setCancelable(false);
  return customConfirmationDialog;
 }



 @Override public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
  final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
  dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                              WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_confirmation_dialog);
  return dialog;
 }


};
```

The problem is that the dialog doesn't appear to want to extend wide enough to accommodate the second button's text, even though there is ample screen space available. 
Does anyone know how to achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/custom_confirmation_dialog_positive_button"
            android:text="Text for button 1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/custom_confirmation_dialog_negative_button"
            android:text="Longer text for button 2"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />
```

Comment: Layout weights only work when the desired dimension value is **"0dp"**, not "wrap_content", nor any other value

Comment: I'm sure I tried "wrap_content" before, but the buttons were not the same size...in relation to the above comment, I was using a width of 0 so should that not work...will try above answer when I get home, but not sure it will work.